# Using CreateProcess, can't get CREATE_NO_WINDOW to supress the console

Tags: c, windows

I want to kick off a process (we'll use notepad for simplicity) without the console window popping up.

I'm sure I've missed something very simple, here is my most simplified test case:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "notepad",        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Comment: Notepad doesn't *have* a console window.  If you are trying to prevent the application's main window from appearing, try using the wShowWindow element of the STARTUPINFO structure.

Comment: If I compile this a cmd window will pop up along with notepad (though I'm actually trying to call a batch file without console, notepad just seemed a more simple example that does the same).

Comment: I think you'll find that's the command window of your application itself.  To confirm, put a printf command ahead of CreateProcess and see whether the output goes to the window you are concerned about.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. Basically I'm just trying to create an executable that will run a batch file in the back ground without popup. Basically the same as these bat-to-exe converters do, but I don't want to blow $40 for what should be a few lines of code. Though I'm a java programmer, not c, so these few lines are getting painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new process(notepad.exe) from a parent process(your console application), and let parent process wait for child process to finish. The console window is the main window of your parent process. You can hide and restore is as show below.

```
// Notice how hiding the console window causes it to disappear from
// the Windows task bar. If you only want to make it minimize, use
// SW_MINIMIZE instead of SW_HIDE.
void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );

    // create a new process and wait for it to finish

    ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_RESTORE );
}
```

Comment: What headers do I need for this? GetConsoleWindow is not recognized. Apologies, I'm a Java EE programmer, not C, nor windows, nor GUI, just trying to scoot by on this one small task.

Comment: You need include file windows.h ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the application subsystem from Console to Windows. In VS2008, this is under linker properties, System.
Then change your main function to:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

and change the code to return an int.

Comment: I'm just using MinGW to compile from text file (not trying to take on anything more than these ~20 lines of code, and I'm not a C nor GUI programmer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you change the application subsystem from Console to Windows using MinGW, add these linker flags:

```
-Wl,-subsystem,windows
```